# why list "table_x" gets the value of the list "table_cards" after "for" is completed?

Tags: python, list, for-loop

why list "table_x" gets the value of the list "table_cards" after "for" is completed? (see image)

[image: image python code]

also the code is here:

```
import random

m = 4

table_x = ['X', 'X', 'X', 'X']

cards = ['10', ' J', ' Q', ' K']

table_cards = table_x
for i in range(m):
    table_cards[i] = random.choice(cards)
    cards.remove(table_cards[i])

print(table_x)

print(table_cards)
```

Comment: Do not post pictures of text that can't be conveniently searched. Further, extract and provide a [mcve], I'm sure you could reduce the code further and that you would solve your problem if you did. As a new user, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: table_cards is now a pointer to table_x, so they are the same when you set them equal to each other. You should either create an entirely new variable or use a copy module to copy the underlying data.

Answer (score 1):

Not a big Python guy. But I believe it's due to

```
table_cards = table_x
```

Rather than copying the values in table_x, you are assigning table_cards to point to the same data as table_x. So for all intents and purposes, they are the same variable.

View it as a math problem.

table_x = 1000

table_cards = table_x

thus, table_cards will also be equal to 1000.

If you did something like table_cards = table_x.copy(), again not a big python guy so not sure the exact symantics. Then table_cards will be a clone, the values, of table_x, rather than a reference to it.

Answer (score 0):

When you did `table_cards = table_x`, table_cards is pointing to the same object in memory (reference) that table_x, each change in both, table_cards or table_x, is applied to the same object. You can check that they are indeed pointing to the same reference with

```py
print(id(table_cards))
print(id(table_x))
```

If you want a copy of the list, without modifying the original, you have to duplicate the list:

```py
table_cards = list(table_x)
# or 
table_cards = table_x.copy()
# or 
table_cards = table_x[:]
```

If you have nested list inside, you have to do a deepcopy from the module:

```py
import copy
table_cards = copy.deepcopy(table_x)
```